# Why is Tommy shooting at the fourth wall?

Tags: plot-explanation, goodfellas

At the end of [Goodfellas](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/?ref_=nv_sr_1),

> Henry is in the witness protection program and says "I get to live the rest of my life like a schnook."

Then, an image of Tommy appears, facing the camera and shooting at it several times. What is the meaning of this scene?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This scene is actually a direct reference to the scene from [The Great Train Robbery](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0000439/) where a similar scene concludes the movie.

Here in this below video at 0:25 secs Martin Scorsese himself mentions the very film and says "...that's why I had Joe Pesci shoot at the camera"

[Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrPJEffTftg&feature=youtu.be)

[image]
You can also find the mention of the same connection in [here](https://www.shmoop.com/goodfellas/ending.html)

> In an interview with the American Film Institute, Scorsese explains
>   the connection between his movie and Porter's: "**Basically, in
>   Goodfellas, it's a bunch of outlaws who do this incredible robbery.
>   And then they all kill each other, and the police get them at the end.
>   It's exactly the same story.**" In other words, Scorsese ripped off the
>   scene. But, you know what they say—imitation is the sincerest form of
>   flattery.

Here, by "Porter" he means [Edwin S. Porter](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0692105/?ref_=tt_ov_dr)

Answer (score 3):

That shot is a reference to the final shot of the 1903 silent film *The Great Train Robbery*, which ends with one of the outlaws shooting at the camera.

See the comparison here on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIoNkifiBms)

Answer (score -2):

His past will always follow him. He’ll always be watching his back. Don’t mistake him for an average nobody, because he once lived the life of a violent criminal, aside men who wouldn’t hesitate to kill. It’s also an homage to an old western movie, when a cowboy shoots directly at the camera.

Comment: Oh ok well that’s just what the director has said it meant.

Comment: _just what the director said it means_ = exactly what it _actually_ meant from the mouth of who did it...